# Page background image in Chrome and Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have an HTML page to which I am applying background image using CSS properties.

The problem is, I want this background image to appear at bottom of the relatively longer page, i.e. the page is to be scrolled to bottom to view the background image.

I applied following:

```
body {
    background: url("images/bg_homepage.png") no-repeat scroll right bottom transparent;
}
```

This works fine for Firefox and Internet Explorer, but doesn't work for Chrome and Safari browsers. Chrome and Safari needs the background-attachment property to be set to "fixed", but that is exactly I don't want.

Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: Works in all the browsers you mentioned for me: http://jsfiddle.net/7CG5z/

Comment: That code, as is, will work in all browsers. You have something else in your code interfering with it.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, and thank you thirtydot for enlightening me about jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want it in your body, you could create an div with and id bg for example :)

and then do something like this

```
#bg {
    background: url("/bg.gif") no-repeat scroll left bottom #FFFFFF;
    bottom: 100px;
    height: 396px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 288px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

if you dont want to use fixed anywhere on the page, it won't work in the major browsers :(

Answer (score 0):

I've done that with

```
body {
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(img/strand_402.jpg);
}
```

Works in all browsers (including IE).